# clickable list of divs in html/css

Tags: css

I want to make horizontal list of divs that is clickable.
I got something like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="/"></a>
        <ul id="list">
            <li id="column1">
                <div></div>
            </li>
            <li id="column2">
                <div></div>
            </li>   
        </ul>   
</div>
```

Styles:

```
#header
{
    height: 200px;
    width:500px;
}

a{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is,an "a" element not in the same place as list, and I want the list to be cliackable.

Comment: what do you mean by "I want list to be clickable"? do you mean you want each li to lead to a different page or you want the whole list to lead to the same page?

Comment: every li leads to the same page, and there should be no spaces between lis

Comment: put your ul list inside the a (between <a> and </a>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want anything to be clickable on your page use javascript event listeners not anchor tags.

When you want an element to be clickable just add an event listener to click action on your client code and define the behaviour of your object.

Use anchor tags only if your object's behaviour is to link to another place.

This will make your code cleaner and easier to read, it will also be easier to place every object where you want it to be.